# Fly-in content boxes on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create two animated boxes that appear on a button click, similar to the one when "About Me" is clicked on http://riccardozanutta.com/ . I wasn't able to figure how he did it, so I decided to go about it using modals. However, I was having trouble with getting both boxes to animate at the same time when I used two separate ones. I am able to get it to work when I have one modal with two different divs such as :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content1">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>About Me</h2>
    <p>blah blah>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content2 col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>Super powers</h2>
    <p>blah blah>
  </div>
</div>
```

However it is just one animation, and they are not joined together as in the one I'd like (with it also having them entering in from separate areas). Are modals what I need to do this, or is there a better way? While I was trying to find examples, I didn't find any that had two boxes. I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can work on [this](https://jsfiddle.net/u77e1zjk/1/) and try to get it as close to your vision as possible. I just forked it, and edited a little to provide you an example and a place to work and find your perfect solution. Good luck!

Here's the example code:
**JS**

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var test1 = document.getElementById('test1');

function translate(elem, x, y) {
  var left = parseInt(css(elem, 'left'), 10),
    top = parseInt(css(elem, 'top'), 10),
    dx = left - x,
    dy = top - y,
    i = 1,
    count = 20,
    delay = 20;

  function loop() {
    if (i >= count) {
      return;
    }
    i += 1;
    elem.style.left = (left - (dx * i / count)).toFixed(0) + 'px';
    elem.style.top = (top - (dy * i / count)).toFixed(0) + 'px';
    setTimeout(loop, delay);
  }

  loop();
}

function css(element, property) {
  return window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(property);
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  var arr;

  if (e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
    test.style.cssText = 'visibility:visible;';
    translate(test, +50, +50);
    test1.style.cssText = 'visibility:visible;';
    translate(test1, +200, +50);
  }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<button title="100 100">Translate to (100, 100)</button>

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div id="test">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>About Me</h2>
    <p>blah blah>
  </div>

  <div id="test1">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>Super powers</h2>
    <p>blah blah>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 500px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#test1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: -500px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try!